# When Trying to Run Code, I get a "Does Not Have Main Method Error"

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, and haven't learned much in my course. Every time I try running my code, I am told that I do not have a main method. However, I thought that 
public void main(String[] args) { 
declares the main method, and it is located at the bottom of my code. Can anyone help revise the code to get it to run?

```
package Java2;
import java.util.Date;

public class tenpoint01 {

public class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    public Time() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public Time(long elapsed) {
    Date date = new Date(elapsed);
    this.hour = date.getHours();
    this.minute = date.getMinutes();
    this.second = date.getSeconds();
}

public Time(int hour, int minute, int second) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
}

private void setTime(long elapsedTime) {
    Date date = new Date(elapsedTime);
    this.hour = date.getHours();
    this.minute = date.getMinutes();
    this.second = date.getSeconds();
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}
/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public void main(String[] args) {
    Time time = new Time();
    Time time2 = new Time(555550000);
    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(time2);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Your main method should be `static`

Comment: Also your `main`  is inside the inner class `Time` , you probably want to put it in the outer class.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
public void main(String[] args) {
```

to

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

resulting in

```
package java2;

import java.util.Date;

public class tenpoint01 {

    public class Time {
        private int hour;
        private int minute;
        private int second;

        public Time() {
            this(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        public Time(long elapsed) {
            Date date = new Date(elapsed);
            this.hour = date.getHours();
            this.minute = date.getMinutes();
            this.second = date.getSeconds();
        }

        public Time(int hour, int minute, int second) {
            this.hour = hour;
            this.minute = minute;
            this.second = second;
        }

        private void setTime(long elapsedTime) {
            Date date = new Date(elapsedTime);
            this.hour = date.getHours();
            this.minute = date.getMinutes();
            this.second = date.getSeconds();
        }

        public int getHour() {
            return hour;
        }

        public int getMinute() {
            return minute;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public void main(String[] args) {
            Time time = new Time();
            Time time2 = new Time(555550000);
            System.out.println(time);
            System.out.println(time2);
        }
    }
}
```

running the above results in

```
16
4
4
4
4
0
```

beeing printed

this should do

Comment: Again, when adding static, I get an error message stating "Illegal static declaration in inner class tenpoint01. Time modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations." Seeing how everybody who's replied has told me to add static between public and void, I’m not sure why it isn't working

Answer (score 1):

The signature of main method is not correct you are missing `static` keyword, the main method should be :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       ^^^^^^
    // your code here
}
```

---

Because you are using Netbeans (is intelligent now) you can just type `public` and presse **Ctrl** + **Enter** and you can see the main method. Or just type `psvm` followed by **tab**, For more details go here  :

- [How to insert main method in Netbeans (shortcut)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636463/how-to-insert-main-method-in-netbeans-shortcut)

Comment: When adding static, I get an error message stating "Illegal static declaration in inner class tenpoint01. Time modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations"

Answer (score 0):

You should add the "static" key word to you main method

To execute what you currently have, should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Time time = new Time();
 Time time2 = new Time(555550000);
 System.out.println(time);
 System.out.println(time2);
```

}

Comment: When adding static, I get an error message stating "Illegal static declaration in inner class tenpoint01. Time modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations"